Can you use position relative and position fixed together on the same container?
I have a container with a pen outline, with a z-index of 5, position: relative. When the viewer choses an underlay graphic with a z-index of -2, position: absolute it works fine, but if they scroll down to see more choices the pen outline scrolls off the screen. How do I keep the pen outline relative AND fixed?
I don't know how to do this.
